# Is it possible to share calendars with Partner Community Users

Tags: event, partner-portal, partner-communities, calendar

I would like to share User calendars with Partner Community Users but I am unable to do it, here is what I did up to now:

- in the User Settings for a specific Internal User A, I added a manual sharing of the User calendar with

  1. the Public Group "All Partner Users"
  2. a Portal Role used for Partner Community Users
  3. a Partner Community User B
- in the Sharing Settings I set the Default External Access for Calendar to "Show Details and Add Events"

Despite this if I login as the Partner Community User B I do not see the Calendar of Internal User A, is there any way to do this ?

Comment: This idea seems to indicate it is not possible yet, however it's speaking about Partner Portal and not Community: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000H3hKAAS